# Exchanging a New Zealand driver's licence for a UK manual car drivers license?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license, new-zealand-citizens

The process for exchanging a NZ drivers license for a UK one seems straight forward. But, how do I go about getting a UK drivers license with being allowed to drive a manual transmission car?

It seems I need some manual transmission proof. I sat my restricted and full license in manual cars.

Comment: I don’t really understand your question. If your NZ licence allows you to drive a manual car surely it indicates that somewhere on the licence itself? NZ is a ‘designated country’ so you should just be exchanging like for like? https://www.gov.uk/exchange-foreign-driving-licence/y/yes/car-or-motorcycle/a-designated-country-countries-with-exchange-agreements-with-great-britain/new-zealand

Comment: @Traveller: There is no indication on an NZ license about whether or not the holder can drive a manual transmission car. The distinction is simply not made in NZ. See https://www.nzta.govt.nz/driver-licences/getting-a-licence/licences-by-vehicle-type/what-you-can-drive/ for what is covered. It may be amusing that steam engines are accounted for, but not transmission types. :)

Comment: Did the DVLA tell you they need proof?

Comment: Yes, the DVLA have requested proof

Comment: @steakunderscore Strange! This thread I found might be helpful to you. Someone there was able to request a "Letter of Entitlement" from NZTA, which convinced the DVLA to issue a manual licence. Please report back if this is successful. https://britishexpats.com/forum/moving-back-uk-61/drivers-licence-exchange-manual-proof-902515/page2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up calling NZTA, the person on the phone seemed to know what I needed.

10 minutes later I had an email from NZTA with a "Letter of Entitlement". I printed this and sent it off with my application. This was sufficient to get my license transferred with manual endorsements.